# Jeditable sends no variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jeditable

I'm trying to send a variable, `intent`, alongside the default variables of *jeditable*. According to the [documentation](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable), the default should send the variables `id` and `value` (I've confirmed that every element I'm using jeditable with has a valid id). I'm using the following code:

**jedit-config.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.jedit').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.editable('service.php', {
            loadtype    :   'GET',
            onblur      :   'submit',
            submitdata  :   { 'intent' : 1 }
        });
    });
});
```

**service.php**

```
$elID = $_GET['id'];
$newText = $_GET['value'];
$intent = $_GET['intent'];

if ($intent == 1) {
    // Do something. Never called.
}

echo $newText;
```

Example of element that jeditable is used on:

```
<li id='listend' class='jedit'>Text here</li>
```

None of my variables (id, value or intent) reach *service.php*. They're all blank. I've sent variables to *service.php* using the following test and it receives it correctly:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "service.php",
    data: "intent=1",
    success: function(result){
        //
    }
});
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Update:**

Looks like variables are being sent by `POST` and not `GET`. `loadtype    :   'GET'` appears to only apply when used in conjunction with the `loadurl` option. I'm seeing if there's a method to use `GET` with the original url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my update, it looks like there's no straightforward means to send data to a url from jeditable by `GET`, only `POST` if not using a `loardurl` option.

The answer is to switch to using `POST` or integrate a method that uses a `loadurl` option. Without this option, `loadtype : 'GET'` does not switch the data submission type to `GET`.